# Firebase fatal crashes not reported

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, crashlytics

We have migrated fabric crashlytics to Firbase crashlytics with below mentioned configurations:

```
firebase crashlytics version - 17.2.2
firebase analytics - 18.0.0
google plug in 4.3.4
android gradle plugin 3.4.0
firbase-core and fire-messaging - 17.0.0
google location, analtyics, play-services - 17.0.0
classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.3.0'
build tools - 29.0.2
targetSdk 29
minimum SDK 15

Below are mentioned logs:
2020-11-12 10:23:34.382 3745-3745/in.spicemudra D/FirebaseCrashlytics: Crashlytics automatic data collection ENABLED by firebase_crashlytics_collection_enabled manifest flag.
2020-11-12 10:23:34.382 3745-3745/in.spicemudra D/FirebaseCrashlytics: Firebase Analytics is available.
2020-11-12 10:23:34.385 3745-3745/in.spicemudra D/FirebaseCrashlytics: Firebase Analytics listener registered successfully.
2020-11-12 10:23:34.395 3745-3745/in.spicemudra D/FirebaseCrashlytics: Reading cached settings...
2020-11-12 10:23:34.396 3745-3745/in.spicemudra D/FirebaseCrashlytics: No cached settings found.
2020-11-12 10:23:34.396 3745-3745/in.spicemudra D/FirebaseCrashlytics: No cached settings data found.
2020-11-12 10:23:34.400 3745-3745/in.spicemudra D/FirebaseCrashlytics: Mapping file ID is: 00000000000000000000000000000000
2020-11-12 10:23:34.401 3745-3745/in.spicemudra I/FirebaseCrashlytics: Initializing Crashlytics 17.2.2
2020-11-12 10:23:34.403 3745-3745/in.spicemudra D/FirebaseCrashlytics: Installer package name is: null
2020-11-12 10:23:34.431 3745-3745/in.spicemudra D/FirebaseCrashlytics: Exception handling initialization successful
2020-11-12 10:23:34.441 3745-3745/in.spicemudra I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
2020-11-12 10:23:34.442 3745-3807/in.spicemudra D/FirebaseCrashlytics: No cached FID; legacy id is null
2020-11-12 10:23:34.443 3745-3807/in.spicemudra D/FirebaseCrashlytics: Created new Crashlytics IID: 604fcece04d942dc96cec99e89aabf9a
2020-11-12 10:23:34.446 3745-3807/in.spicemudra D/FirebaseCrashlytics: Opening a new session with ID 5FACBFCE01AF-0001-0EA1-F8A9774FCBDF
2020-11-12 10:23:34.471 3745-3745/in.spicemudra D/FirebaseCrashlytics: Crashlytics automatic data collection ENABLED by API.
2020-11-12 10:23:34.478 3745-3807/in.spicemudra D/FirebaseCrashlytics: Initialization marker file created.
2020-11-12 10:23:34.478 3745-3807/in.spicemudra D/FirebaseCrashlytics: Registered Firebase Analytics event receiver for breadcrumbs
2020-11-12 10:23:34.478 3745-3807/in.spicemudra D/FirebaseCrashlytics: Finalizing previously open sessions.
2020-11-12 10:23:34.481 3745-3807/in.spicemudra D/FirebaseCrashlytics: No open sessions to be closed.
2020-11-12 10:23:34.481 3745-3807/in.spicemudra D/FirebaseCrashlytics: Closed all previously open sessions
2020-11-12 10:23:34.482 3745-3807/in.spicemudra D/FirebaseCrashlytics: No reports are available.
2020-11-12 10:23:34.484 3745-3807/in.spicemudra D/FirebaseCrashlytics: Initialization marker file removed: true
2020-11-12 10:23:34.505 3745-3807/in.spicemudra D/FirebaseCrashlytics: Persisting non-fatal event for session 5FACBFCE01AF00010EA1F8A9774FCBDF
2020-11-12 10:23:34.523 3745-3807/in.spicemudra D/FirebaseCrashlytics: No log data to include with this event.
2020-11-12 10:23:34.533 3745-3807/in.spicemudra D/FirebaseCrashlytics: Crashlytics is logging non-fatal exception "java.io.FileNotFoundException: spicemudranewdatabases" from thread AsyncTask #1
2020-11-12 10:23:34.539 3745-3807/in.spicemudra D/FirebaseCrashlytics: No log data to include with this event.
2020-11-12 10:23:34.726 3745-3826/in.spicemudra D/FirebaseCrashlytics: Received Analytics message: 3 Bundle[{params=Bundle[{_o=auto, _sid=1605156814}], name=_s, timestampInMillis=1605156814627}]
2020-11-12 10:23:34.848 3745-3829/in.spicemudra D/FirebaseCrashlytics: Requesting settings from https://firebase-settings.crashlytics.com/spi/v2/platforms/android/gmp/1:247134278237:android:0c17cbfde8bacff4/settings
2020-11-12 10:23:34.848 3745-3829/in.spicemudra D/FirebaseCrashlytics: Settings query params were: {display_version=3.1.6, source=1, instance=1e3a4b1449c2e301a660e1ef82a8d3a6d1c52ad3, build_version=91}
2020-11-12 10:23:34.864 3745-3826/in.spicemudra D/FirebaseCrashlytics: Received Analytics message: 3 Bundle[{params=Bundle[{_o=app, content_type=MudraApplication- Current Language, content=Current Language Hindi, item_id=HINDI}], name=select_content, timestampInMillis=1605156814505}]
2020-11-12 10:23:35.015 3745-3826/in.spicemudra D/FirebaseCrashlytics: Received Analytics message: 3 Bundle[{params=Bundle[{_o=auto, _sc=SplashActivity, _si=-6782287162466495586}], name=_vs, timestampInMillis=1605156814974}]
2020-11-12 10:23:35.143 3892-3892/? I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
2020-11-12 10:23:36.203 3745-3833/in.spicemudra D/FirebaseInstanceId: topic sync succeeded
2020-11-12 10:23:38.376 3745-3829/in.spicemudra D/FirebaseCrashlytics: Settings request ID: null
2020-11-12 10:23:38.376 3745-3829/in.spicemudra D/FirebaseCrashlytics: Settings result was: 200
2020-11-12 10:23:38.377 3745-3829/in.spicemudra D/FirebaseCrashlytics: Writing settings to cache file...
2020-11-12 10:23:38.380 3745-3829/in.spicemudra D/FirebaseCrashlytics: Loaded settings: {"settings_version":3,"cache_duration":86400,"features":{"collect_logged_exceptions":true,"collect_reports":true,"collect_analytics":false,"prompt_enabled":false,"push_enabled":false,"firebase_crashlytics_enabled":false},"app":{"status":"activated","update_required":false,"report_upload_variant":2,"native_report_upload_variant":2},"fabric":{"org_id":"548b51620776fe5280000001","bundle_id":"in.spicemudra"},"expires_at":1605243218377}
2020-11-12 10:23:38.908 3745-3826/in.spicemudra D/FirebaseCrashlytics: Received Analytics message: 3 Bundle[{params=Bundle[{_o=auto, _et=4055, _sc=SplashActivity, _si=-6782287162466495586}], name=_e, timestampInMillis=1605156818844}]
2020-11-12 10:23:39.035 3745-3826/in.spicemudra D/FirebaseCrashlytics: Received Analytics message: 3 Bundle[{params=Bundle[{_o=auto, _pc=SplashActivity, _pi=-6782287162466495586, _sc=LanguageSelectionActivity, _si=-6782287162466495585}], name=_vs, timestampInMillis=1605156818956}]
2020-11-12 10:23:45.255 3745-3826/in.spicemudra D/FirebaseCrashlytics: Received Analytics message: 3 Bundle[{params=Bundle[{_o=app, _sc=LanguageSelectionActivity, _si=-6782287162466495585, content_type=LanguageSelectionActivity- Language Selected, content=Selected Language English, item_id=ENGLISH}], name=select_content, timestampInMillis=1605156825197}]
2020-11-12 10:23:45.378 3745-3826/in.spicemudra D/FirebaseCrashlytics: Received Analytics message: 3 Bundle[{params=Bundle[{_o=auto, _et=6321, _sc=LanguageSelectionActivity, _si=-6782287162466495585}], name=_e, timestampInMillis=1605156825329}]
2020-11-12 10:23:45.430 3745-3826/in.spicemudra D/FirebaseCrashlytics: Received Analytics message: 3 Bundle[{params=Bundle[{_o=app, content_type=REFERAL, content=ReferralIntentServiceNew started, item_id=REFERRALINTENTSERVICENEW STARTED FROM WELCOME ACTIVITY}], name=select_content, timestampInMillis=1605156825334}]
2020-11-12 10:23:45.548 3745-3826/in.spicemudra D/FirebaseCrashlytics: Received Analytics message: 3 Bundle[{params=Bundle[{_o=auto, _pc=LanguageSelectionActivity, _pi=-6782287162466495585, _sc=WelcomeActivity, _si=-6782287162466495584}], name=_vs, timestampInMillis=1605156825496}]
2020-11-12 10:23:45.608 3745-3826/in.spicemudra D/FirebaseCrashlytics: Received Analytics message: 3 Bundle[{params=Bundle[{_o=app, _sc=WelcomeActivity, _si=-6782287162466495584, content_type=REFERAL, content=service Started, item_id=REFERRALINTENTSERVICENEW STARTED}], name=select_content, timestampInMillis=1605156825350}]
2020-11-12 10:23:45.709 3745-3826/in.spicemudra D/FirebaseCrashlytics: Received Analytics message: 3 Bundle[{params=Bundle[{_o=app, _sc=WelcomeActivity, _si=-6782287162466495584, content_type=REFERAL, content=null EXTRAS, item_id=EXTRAS IS NULL}], name=select_content, timestampInMillis=1605156825351}]
2020-11-12 10:23:45.993 3745-3826/in.spicemudra D/FirebaseCrashlytics: Received Analytics message: 3 Bundle[{params=Bundle[{_o=app, _sc=WelcomeActivity, _si=-6782287162466495584, content_type=REFERAL, content=InstallReferrerResponse.OK, item_id=INSTALLREFERRERRESPONSE.OK}], name=select_content, timestampInMillis=1605156825524}]
2020-11-12 10:23:46.142 3745-3826/in.spicemudra D/FirebaseCrashlytics: Received Analytics message: 3 Bundle[{params=Bundle[{_o=app, _sc=WelcomeActivity, _si=-6782287162466495584, content_type=REFERAL, content=utm_source=google-play&utm_medium=organic, item_id=GOOGLEREFERAL_URLUTM_SOURCE=GOOGLE-PLAY&UTM_MEDIUM=ORGANIC}], name=select_content, timestampInMillis=1605156825535}]
2020-11-12 10:23:46.280 3745-3826/in.spicemudra D/FirebaseCrashlytics: Received Analytics message: 3 Bundle[{params=Bundle[{_o=app, _sc=WelcomeActivity, _si=-6782287162466495584, content_type=ReferralIntentServiceNew- UTM_SOURCE_EVENT, content=UTM_SOURCE_EVENT, item_id=GOOGLE-PLAY}], name=select_content, timestampInMillis=1605156825557}]
2020-11-12 10:23:46.424 3745-3826/in.spicemudra D/FirebaseCrashlytics: Received Analytics message: 3 Bundle[{params=Bundle[{_o=app, _sc=WelcomeActivity, _si=-6782287162466495584, content_type=ReferralIntentServiceNew- UTM_MEDIUM_EVENT, content=UTM_MEDIUM_EVENT, item_id=ORGANIC}], name=select_content, timestampInMillis=1605156825557}]
2020-11-12 10:23:46.611 3745-3826/in.spicemudra D/FirebaseCrashlytics: Received Analytics message: 3 Bundle[{params=Bundle[{_o=auto, _pc=WelcomeActivity, _pi=-6782287162466495584, _sc=RequiredPermissionActivity, _si=-6782287162466495583}], name=_vs, timestampInMillis=1605156826551}]
2020-11-12 10:23:46.690 3745-3826/in.spicemudra D/FirebaseCrashlytics: Received Analytics message: 3 Bundle[{params=Bundle[{_o=auto, _et=980, _sc=WelcomeActivity, _si=-6782287162466495584}], name=_e, timestampInMillis=1605156826519}]
2020-11-12 10:23:47.480 3745-3826/in.spicemudra D/FirebaseCrashlytics: Received Analytics message: 3 Bundle[{params=Bundle[{_o=auto, _et=1000, _sc=RequiredPermissionActivity, _si=-6782287162466495583}], name=_e, timestampInMillis=1605156827409}]
2020-11-12 10:23:47.876 3745-3826/in.spicemudra D/FirebaseCrashlytics: Received Analytics message: 3 Bundle[{params=Bundle[{_o=auto, _pc=RequiredPermissionActivity, _pi=-6782287162466495583, _sc=LoginActivity, _si=-6782287162466495582}], name=_vs, timestampInMillis=1605156827818}]
2020-11-12 10:24:14.124 761-1556/? D/DnsProxyBlocker: add uid(10225) for Firewall
2020-11-12 10:24:14.180 761-1556/? D/DnsProxyBlocker: remove uid(10225) for Firewall
```

I am able to get non fatal crashes but fatal are not reported.

Thanks in Advance